# What was the name of Rachel and Leah's mother?

Tags: names, vayeitzei

What was the name of Lavan's wife, the mother of Rachel and Leah?

Comment: Purim Torah answer: She was called the First Lady (Think about it).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have seen Adina mentioned online, but I don't have a source...

Comment: I see it in Sefer Hayashar (http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&pgnum=97, last line).

Comment: 9 upvotes? Nothing personal, just a little surprising.

Comment: Well gotta ask those 9 people. Do keep in mind this was written in the really early days of the site. Things were different back then. Plus seeing it online *is* actually a source, just not a very good one. And don't forget the checkmark - Gershon apparently was happy with it too.

Comment: @DoubleAA Alex found a source, so I guess that it's good

Comment: @ShmuelBrin a pretty shady source.

Answer (score 7):

The sefer *Tiferes Shlomo al HaTorah* in *Parshas Vayetze* brings a number of answers to the question of how Yaakov was allowed to marry two sisters. One of the answers is that Rachel and Leah were born to Lavan from two different wives and therefore not prohibited to Yaakov. In light of this, you may have to change your question to "What were the names of Rachel and Leah's mothers?

Answer (score 3):

Adina.  It comes from The Book of Enoch, I believe.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!  If you can provide a more precise source, it would greatly improve the value of this answer

Comment: What is "The Book of Enoch" And where can I find it?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Did you even search Google? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch

Answer (score 2):

It's also in Jasher 28:28  Adinah                  This book is also mentioned in Genesis.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4549/what-was-the-name-of-rachel-and-leahs-mother/44858#comment5164_4561 But when someone besides Alex quotes it, it gets downvoted...

Comment: @DoubleAA, Sefer HaYashar is mentioned in Genesis? And this particular book is the Sefer HaYashar mentioned in Tanach? (Not that I downvoted, but Alex didn't make those claims).

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it's just the English