# Is it permissible for a Jewish woman to marry a Muslim man and vice versa?

Tags: halacha, islam, intermarriage

As both Abrahamic religions, Islam and Judaism have the same God and share a common law then how do rabbis see the marriage of a Jewish woman marrying a Muslim man and vice versa? What about their children? Would they be Jewish as they have a Jewish mother? Please comment and explain.

Comment: Jews and Muslims have a common *history*, but we don't have the same law and whether we worship the same god is controversial.

Comment: @Monica Cellio What makes the God controversial between a Jew and a Muslim? As far as i know both worship the same omnipotent, one single God. FYI: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14461/is-there-any-difference-between-jewish-g-d-and-muslim-g-d

Comment: No, it is not permissible. Jews must marry Jews. Alex provides some sources, but the answer is simply no.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Jews and Muslims ostensibly worship the same G-d. Maimonides believed such, and I don't think any Posek has ever questioned that (but I could be proven wrong). In any case, Muslims profess to worship the G-d of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, and they believe in His unity, indivisibility, etc. They believe He created the universe and that Moses gave His law to the people. I don't know enough about Islam to comment on the rest, but it seems they meet our criteria to be considered upstanding monotheists.

Comment: @MonicaCellio (and anyone else reading), I just want to clarify that I agree with your first point about not having the same laws, and there are many other considerations involved. Jews cannot follow Islam (by that I mean that Judaism does not sanction it), but from the Jewish perspective, Muslims most probably worship the Jewish G-d. There are also many, many, many Muslims who want to kill many, many, many Jews. But that is a separate topic. When I wrote "upstanding", I meant purely in regard to their monotheism.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's not as controversial as I thought. :-)  (This isn't an area I've studied, but I thought I'd heard that in several places, including this site.  Perhaps not.)  It's certainly true, though, that if Muslims and Jews follow the same God, they don't understand him to be telling them exactly the same things.

Comment: @SethJ - the Meiri states (I'll have to find where) that Islam is idolatrous because in Mecca inside the [? don't remember what it's called] there are three pillars and there representing different 'deities' and there was a muslim custom to throw stones at one of the pillars representing the devil. He considers it a form of worship called 'Zorek even l'Markulis'.

Comment: @afuna find out where, and you'll have proven me wrong.

Comment: @SethJ - see Ibn Ezra Daniel 11:30: 

 כי יש במיכ"א שיקוץ עד היום והלא מרקוליס שאליו יחוגו כל ישמעאל ממזרח וממערב לזרוק אבנים שם

Comment: @afuna that's not the Meiri, and that's not a Pesak.

Comment: @SethJ - you're right. Maybe I heard it misattributed. So what? They are both Rishonim. Re. being a Posek, i think that is being pedantic. If Ibn Ezra interprets the practice as markulis, there is certainly room for a Psek to *question* their halachic status.

Comment: @afuna You are nitpicking a word that I used three years ago in a comment explaining a previous comment regarding yet another comment. Who is being pedantic?

Comment: @SethJ I mean to say that if you have never heard of any authority that holds arabs to be idol worshipers, the Ibn Ezra should suffice as a novel opinion, albeit not a a *posek* or a *pesak*. The pedantry I was referring to was in your most recent comment, that it's not a Pesak (I assumed that you wrote that to stress what you had previously written: a *Posek*).

Comment: @afuna, I was stressing that point, yes. Because the question is one of Jewish law. And Ibn 'Ezra is not regarded as a decisor of Jewish law whose rulings we use today.

Comment: @SethJ - The Meiri that discusses if they are idol-worshipers is in Avodah Zara 57. You can find other sources (Smag, Eshkol) in Yabia Omer vol. 7 Yoreh Deah #7. Sorry if I was being sensitive - I had felt your original response to my post was somewhat snarky - I don't see the difference    between quoting the Meiri or Ibn Ezra - both are generally not considered *poskim*, and also I wasn't trying to prove anyone wrong , just trying to add an interesting source to the conversation.

Comment: `Also how is it like to falling in love and then marrying that person beloging to either religions` this line is primarily opinion based. I will exercise my line item veto to remove it.

Answer (score 17):

For many purposes of Jewish law, Muslims are treated exactly on a par with members of other faiths.

Judaism doesn't recognize intermarriage - in either direction - as valid ([Code of Jewish Law, Even Haezer 44:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14398&pgnum=174)); indeed, a Jewish man would have to be prepared to give up his life rather than have sexual relations with a non-Jewish woman ([Shach, Yoreh De'ah 157:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&pgnum=156)). The same rules, then, apply regardless of the non-Jewish partner's nationality or religion.

As for any children from such a union, the usual rule applies: if the mother is Jewish then they are too, and if not, they are not.

Comment: I see! Then why Abraham(the first Jew according to Judaism)  had sexual relations with Hagar who happened to be among the gentiles? Please explain.

Comment: @Maxood, That's worth asking as a separate question. But first, I recommend that you take a look at [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4078/2) [three](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4088/2) [questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11986/2) that deal with the question of how much of the Torah the Patriarchs were required to keep in general, and with respect to marriage in particular (although intermarriage, in particular, is not discussed there).

Comment: Abraham was not fully Jewish, nor was his son Ishmael and his son's son Esau. The Jewish people only came into existence later.

Answer (score 6):

This requires making a distinction between Jewish peoplehood & religion and the Jewish faith:

The Jewish faith is a universal one: strict monotheism combined with a basic set of moral & societal rules (the *sheva mitzvos b’nei Noach*, the seven Noachide Laws). Any human being that follows these guidelines is on the correct path. Islam has no special status here, except to the extent that it (and Unitarian Christianity) also teaches strict monotheism.

The Jewish people have a special role in this scheme; we are bound by a special Covenant with God and have many additional laws to follow. Anyone can choose to join us and take on these obligations, but once accepted these obligations may not be put down. (This is one reason Judaism discourages converts: it’s much easier to be a righteous non-Jew than an observant Jew.)

That said, marriage between a Jew of either sex and a non-Jew is not allowed. Husband & wife must be bound to the same covenant with God: either the general one for all humanity or the particular one for Jews.

In many circumstances, a non-Jew can convert to Judaism, joining the Jewish people, and marry a born Jew. Such conversions are often suspect, though, with the convert’s true commitment (and hence the validity of the conversion) sometimes in question. Many Rabbis will therefore be reluctant to convert someone who is in a pre-existing relationship with a Jew.

In case of a violation of these rules, when a Jew & a non-Jew have children together, Jewish Law considers the children to inherit their mother’s status: if she is a Jew, so are her children, and *vice versa*.

Comment: Isn't this sexism? You are prefering a woman over a man for carrying religious identity. Why? Where it is written in the Torah that a person whose mother is a jew happens to be a jew? Please explain

Comment: All the 7 Laws of Noah are completely observant for person to be a practising Muslim in Islam. Thngs like Idolatory, Theft, Murder, Sexual Immorality, Blasphemy, Eating flesh of an alive animal and Establising courts of law are what Islam has emphasized from day 1! FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noachide_Laws FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Shari%27a. So according to you if a Muslim whose mother was a Jew is also a Jew..is it? A person who is an atheist si also a jew just because this person has a Jewish mother...is it? How?

Comment: Because Jewishness is a matter of national identity as much as religious observance. Every member of the Jewish nation is obligated to observe the Jewish religion. A Jew who practices the basic rules of morality via Islam or any non-Jewish faith may be a wonderful person but is failing in his duty as a Jew.

Comment: @Maxood, the question of _why_ Judaism follows matrilineality is a valid one, but is too big to be discussed in comments here; ask it as a distinct question.

Comment: You are confusing between "Judaism" and "Zionism" when you say that "Jewishness is a matter of national identity". Can you tell me how a Jew who practices the basic rules of morality via Islam fails his duty as a Jew? Do you know that usury or interest on loan is completely forbidden in Islam while Jews allow it for the non-jews to pay them interest so what do you say about that? Where are the jewish moral guidelines now?

Comment: @Maxood, the tone of your questions is making me wonder whether you want to understand or provoke. It is difficult to properly express nuances of speech online, so I shall give you the benefit of the doubt & try to answer your questions.

Comment: @Maxood, _re_ Judaism & Zionism: The “national identity” aspect of Judaism is distinct from Zionism. Jews, observant of Judaism or not, share a national identity somewhat similar (but not identical) to the Muslim concept of the _Ummah_. Zionism is one particular way of expressing this identity by seeking to live in a Jewish state in the land of Ancient Israel. If you want to understand the distinction better, ask for an explanation as its own question.

Comment: @Maxood, _re_ interest: There is nothing immoral about lending money with a reasonable interest rate. However, one of my duties as a Jew is to charitably lend to my fellow Jew forgoing this profit. See, _e.g._, [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/795/70) or questions tagged [tag:lending-interest-ribbis].

Comment: This is where the difference in moral guidelines lie! You being a Jew can only recoginze Jews as your brothers. While in Islam, everyone being the children of Adam belong to the same fraternity. You can lend us money on interest but Islam forbids us to lend money to you or anyone on interest!

Comment: Then please tell me that why the Jews living in Yemen and elsewhere are against Zionism?

Comment: @Maxood, are you trying to get information about Jewish life and learning or to promote your views about the differences between modern sensibilities and Judaism, between Islam and Judaism, and between Judaism and Zionism? Many of your comments in this thread seem to indicate the latter. If that's so, you may want to try a blog or open-ended discussion forum, rather than this Judaism Q&A site.

Comment: @Maxood and J. C. Salomon, debating the relative merits of Judaism and Islam is off-topic here. If that thread of conversation, or other off-topic threads, continue in these comments, I'll probably have to lock this post from further comments.

Comment: @Isaac Moses We are children of Abraham(may peace and blessings be upon him). Our interpretation is different but we share common roots and our core law is mor or less the same. What is really makes things bitter and conflicting when facts are distorted and concoctions take their place because of sectarianism and prejeudice. I am here to learn, search and seek the real facts based on genuine theological evidence. I presume that this forum is not based on one Jewish sect but represents Judaism in its entireity. Hope this forum helps me in my objective!

Comment: @J. C. Salomon Dear brother! You and others here are always welcome to chat with me at a convnient time that suits us. Lets refer to the sciptures and seek the truth together!

Comment: @Maxood Welcome to MY.  We appreciate your questions, however, site protocol asks you to list each question separately instead of discussing in the comments.

Comment: @LN6595 Understandable. I shall be posting the discussions separately. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While it is not forbidden on a biblical level to marry fellow monotheists, it is forbidden derabanan to marry anyone who doesn't convert to Judaism.

Comment: Please source your answers (as already mentioned), otherwise they should rather be comments. Also make sure you add to what has been said before