# Does a Jew need to obtain a get if his ex-wife is not Jewish?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, divorce, intermarriage

A Jewish man marries a non-Jewish woman in a Jewish ceremony, with a ketubah, under the supervision of a non-orthodox rabbi.

Later on, the couple obtains a civil divorce.

May the Jewish man now marry a Jewish woman without the need for a get, since his ex-wife was not Jewish? Or is a get required?

Comment: Jeremy, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Regarding your personal status and what you should do in your situation, I recommend that you [talk to your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146), something you'll likely have to do to anyway to enact a Jewish marriage; we don't offer [personal rabbinic advice](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734). If you'd like, you can [edit] this question to be about a general case rather than about yourself, and then use any information you get to inform your conversation with your rabbi.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23417 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14777 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29893.

Answer (score 12):

A non-Jew is in the category of Ein Kiddushin Tofsin Bam (marriage does not 'catch' them). ([Mishna Kiddushin 3:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kiddushin.3.12), [ShA EH 44](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7659):8)

Thus there was not and cannot be a marriage between a Jew and a non-Jew, and giving a *Get* would serve no purpose as there is no marriage to sever.

Comment: It should be noted that in cases of the reverse; a Jewish woman "married" to a non-Jewish man, it is not unheard of for Gittin to be written upon "divorce" for the very practical reason that in the event that she wishes to remarry she doesnt need to go through the hassle of proving that her first husband wasnt Jewish. I believe that R. Nota Greenblatt writes such Gittin particularly in cases such as where the husband underwent a Reform or conservative conversion, where although no halachic change has been effected, a future beis din might not be clear about the details and make problems with

Comment: her future marriage.