# Who was the wife of Levi (according to Sefer HaYashar)?

Tags: history, women, historical-figures, shevatim-12-tribes

What was the name of Levi's wife?

I am specifically looking for the answer which is given in Sefer HaYashar, but I can't seem to find it. Does anyone know who Sefer HaYashar says the wife of Levi is?

Comment: Paneach razza in parshas Pinchas says in the name of a medrash that her name was Osah, as in the passuk in pinchas 26 59 that was born osah (lit. her) to levi.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01593.html) sefer hayashar? (There are [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_haYashar) by that name so and since I've never read any of them I don't know which one you're looking for).

Comment: @Bachrach44 No that's a work of Chiddushim by Rabbeinu Tam. The OP refers to a late biblical Midrash by the same name, both named after the extra biblical book Sefer Hayashar referenced in Shmuel and Yehoshua.

Answer (score 4):

In parshas Vayeishev the Seffer Hayashar says her name was Adina.

Answer (score 4):

in sefer hayashar parshas vayeishev page kuf ayin beis (172) "(transltated from the hebrew) ...and to yovav ben yokton two daughters the older one was adinah and the younger was aridah and levi took adinah and yissachar took aridah"

so the answer to your question is acording to sefer hayashar the name of levis wife is adinah

Comment: That's odd in light of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4549/what-was-the-name-of-rachel-and-leahs-mother/4561#comment5164_4561

Comment: im not sure what on that page your referring to please be more specific

Comment: The link is to a comment which claims Adina is Lavan's wife, and hence Levi's grandmother.

Comment: Assuming they were two separate people

Comment: No. It can still be odd even if they were separate people. How many repeating names do you have in Breishit?

Comment: Sefer hayashar gives the name adina only to levis wife other meforshim say lavans wife had that name there are probably different mesorahs to each miforash regarding the different names

Comment: You didn't follow my link apparently. Sefer Hayashar gives the name Adina for Lavan's wife.

Comment: @DoubleAA Quite a few, actually. There are 4 "Chanoch"s, 3 "Shva"s, two "Dedan"s, 2 "Aram"s, 2 "Lemech"s, 2 "Utz"s and 2 "Nachor"s.