# Why didn't Yaakov divorce Leah?

Tags: marriage, divorce

It would appear that Yaakov did not intend to marry Leah. If so, why did he simply not divorce her either immediately after the wedding, or at any later point?

---

Related: [1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4088/yaakov-marrying-two-sisters/12791#12791), [2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48841/should-yaakov-have-married-rachel/48847#48847)

Comment: Moreover why wasn't it a Mekach Taut and no divorce would be necessary?

Comment: A friend drafted a really interesting piece on this. I told him it was too far out, and I think I inadvertently discouraged him from posting it on his blog. Gonna reach out, Beli Neder, and try to get him to post it. If his theory is right, however, the question would really be, why didn't Ya'akov divorce Rachel?

Comment: @DoubleAA, can you say Mekach Taut by a Ben Noach? I would think that only comes into play once Kiddushin is involved.

Comment: @yis Interesting! That gets into what a nonjewish marriage is, and likely kicking her out as mekach taut vs divorce is about the same thing fr them.

Comment: @Yishai, [*ahem*](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4078/5).

Comment: @SethJ, I think most everyone agrees that they got the Chumras of both, even taking that statement very literally (and ignoring the Ramban that says the whole thing only applied in Eretz Yisroel).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Medrash Rabba Vayetze 71](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=173&hilite=) says that he did not divorce Leah since she had children.

> כיוון שראה יעקב מעשים שרימתה לאה באחותה, נתן דעתו לגרשה, וכיוון שפקדה
>   ה' בבנים אמר לאמן של אלו אני מגרש

Comment: כחי וראשית אוני