# Avuncular marriage in the Torah

Tags: halacha, marriage, moshe-rabbeinu, family-members

Isn't avuncular marriage considered incest in Judaism? Doesn't that mean that Moses was a product of incest since his mother was married to her nephew?

Comment: Why do you think it is?

Comment: I have no clue. That's why I asked.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9057/603

Comment: You didnt ask "is it" you asked "isnt it" which makes an implicit assumption. No matter...answer on the way...

Comment: And Ya'akov married two sisters and Shimon (according to some) married Dina and Sara was Avraham's niece Yiskah and Yehoshua married a zonah (rachav) and...

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76051/yocheved-is-the-daughter-of-who

Answer (score 8):

Avunculate marriage is marriage between an uncle and a niece or between an aunt and a nephew.

The latter is Biblically forbidden (Leviticus 18:12-3). The former, however, is not, and the Talmud actually encourages it (Yevamot 62b-63a).

Interestingly, R. Saul Lieberman z"l contends that the Talmudic encouragement for marrying one's niece, was specifically meant to counter a Sadduceean position that banned marriage to nieces, in spite of the lack of explicit Biblical prohibition. (Tosefta Ki-fshutah (New York: JTS, 1973) pg. 915).

Regarding Moses, he was indeed the product of a union that was subsequently forbidden after the Law was given. (Exod. 6:20). Regarding a possible violation of Noahide incest laws, some state that she was a paternal aunt, rather than a maternal aunt. (Yalkut Shim'oni B'reshit: 25, cf. Rashi Exod. 6:20). Others are of the opinion that Noahide law does not include a prohibition to marry an aunt (cf. Sanhedrin 58a, Hilkhot Issurei Biah 14:10).

Interestingly, [Hizkuni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hezekiah_ben_Manoah) suggest [in his commentary to (Exod. 6:20)](http://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni,_Exodus.6.20.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that Moses' lineage wasn't a bug; it was a feature! It is good for a leader to have some stain in his past to prevent him from excessively glorying over his subjects.

For a lengthy discussion of all things avuncular and Jewish, see [here](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2015/10/avunculate-marriage-in-bible.html).