# How did Amram (Mose's father) marry Yochevet his aunt?

Tags: halacha, tanach

It is known that according to Halacha it is forbidden to marry your aunt. How come that Amram (Mose's father) married his aunt - Yochevet. As mentioned in [Exodus 6:20](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0206.htm#20):

> וַיִּקַּח עַמְרָם אֶת-יוֹכֶבֶד דּוֹדָתוֹ, לוֹ לְאִשָּׁה

Moreover, the children of these marriage were 3 holy people and Tzadikim: Moshe, Aharon and Miriam.

Comment: When did that become the "halacha"?

Comment: As far as I know the Avot as well as the 12 tribes and their offsprings obeyed the Halacha before getting the Tora. (There is also a discussion how Jacob married 2 sisters)

Comment: Whether the Torah was kept (by whom and where are up for discussion) in part or in whole, voluntarily or by obligation is a separate discussion which might call this question into doubt.

Comment: Can you source the idea that "their offsprings" also kept all the Halachos? I think it's relatively widely known that it's written that the Avot kept all the laws, but where does it say that Amram did too? And it's obvious that _all_ their offsprings didn't keep all the Halachos, as there are a myriad of sources saying that the Bnai Yisrael in Egypt sunk to low levels.

Comment: Even if you claim that Amram didn't need to keep this Halacha. This issue is relevant to Arayot. So even if he didn't need to keep it, how come that this marriage brought such high level souls like Moses, Aharon and Miriam that came from Arayot relation?

Comment: why ask this here and not ablout Avraham and Sarah?

Comment: See the end of Nefesh HaChaim Shaar Alef. He says Amram kept the Torah and explains how he married his aunt. I summarize what he says [here](https://parshaponders.com/vayeitzei-5778/). Maybe I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yocheved is the daughter of who?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76051/yocheved-is-the-daughter-of-who)

Comment: Thanks @robev! It has some answers that can be copied and pasted here. However, I'm looking for some more like the one below and one like you mentioned in Nefesh HaChaim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It was before Mathan Torah
2. A heavenly voice told him to, and he listened and they cleaved to HBKH, and reciprocally the Shekhinah bound to them actually in their very act and never left them and Moshe who went out from him.

Zohar II 11b top

> "And a [great] man went" – this is Amram.  "And took a daughter of
> Levi (bat-Levi)" – this is Yokheved. A *bat*-kol (heavenly voice) came
> down and told him to be matched with her, for behold the time of
> Yisrael's salvation has come, via the son that will be born by her.
> And HKBH helped him, for we've learned a tanya: The Shekhinah rested
> on his bed, and their will, in one cleaving was in the Shekhinah, and
> for this reason the Shekhinah never departed from that son they bore,
> to fulfill the scripture (Lev. 11:45), "Holy yourselves and you shall
> be holy."  A mortal who sanctifies himself below, HKBH sanctifies him
> above.  Just as their will was in the bond of the Shekhinah, so too
> that Shekhinah bonded in that actual act that they did.
>
> Said R' Yitzchak, Fortunate are those tzadikim that their will is in
> the bond of HKBH always.  Just as they always bind to him, so too He
> binds to them, and never leaves them.  Woe to the wicked, that their
> will and their bond is in distancing from Him.  And not enough for
> them that they distance from Him, rather they bind to the Sitra Achra.
> Come and see: Amram who bonded with HKBH, Moshe came out from him, for
> HKBH never left him, and the Shekhinah clung to him perpetually.
> Fortunate is their lot!

---

> וילך איש, דא עמרם, ויקח את בת לוי, דא יוכבד, ובת קול נחתת ואמרת ליה
> לאזדווגא בה, דהא קריב זמנא דפורקנא דישראל על ידא דברא דאתיליד מנייהו,
> וקודשא בריך הוא סייע ביה, דתנינן שכינתא שריא על ערסייהו, ורעותא דלהון
> בדבקותא חדא הוה בה בשכינתא, ועל דא לא אתעדי שכינתא מההוא ברא דאולידו,
> לקיימא דכתיב (ויקרא יא מד) והתקדשתם והייתם קדושים, בר נש דמקדש גרמיה
> מלרע, קודשא בריך הוא מקדש ליה לעילא, כמה דרעותא דלהון הוה בדבקותא
> דשכינתא, הכי אתדבקא שכינתא בההוא עובדא ממש דעבדו. אמר רבי יצחק, זכאין
> אינון צדיקיא דרעותא דלהון בדבקותא דקודשא בריך הוא תדיר, וכמה דאינון
> מתדבקין ביה תדיר, הכי נמי איהו אתדבק בהו, ולא שביק לון לעלמין, ווי
> לרשיעייא דרעותא דלהון ודבקותא דלהון מתרחקא מניה, ולא די להו דמתרחקן
> מניה, אלא דמתדבקן בסטרא אחרא, תא חזי עמרם דאתדבק ביה בקודשא בריך הוא,
> נפיק מניה משה, דקודשא בריך הוא לא אעדי מניה לעלמין, ושכינתא אתדבקת
> בהדיה תדיד, זכאה חולקיה: