# Yeshiva curriculum prior to Matan Torah

Tags: torah-study

What was being learned and discussed in the diffrent yeshivas that were established prior to the giving of the torah?

Example: Eliezer was studying in yeshivah, The Yeshivah Shem V'ever, also The Yeshivah established in (goshen?) Mitzrayim.

Comment: Chazal teach us, that Avraham Avinu's "Maseches Avoda Zara" contained 400 (!) chapters. That's a huge syllabus.

Comment: The Noahide code only enumerates the basic core tenets. However, there are many corollaries to each of these tenets; all of which need to be elaborated and expanded upon and be observed.

Comment: Probably all the laws we have now - it even says that Yaakov studied with Yosef the laws of Eglah Arufah

Comment: @שלום please cite the source for that. thanks

Comment: Beraishis Rabbah 95:3; Rashi on Beraishis 45:27

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/yeshivat-sheim-veiver