# Abraham and Matzah

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, passover-seder-hagada, matzah, kabbalat-hatorah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avot keeping Mitzvot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot)

According to some traditions, Abraham was completely Torah observant.  Would this include the mitzvah of eating matzah?  Or participating in the seder?  If so, how would he have understood these things?

Comment: rashi on Bereishit 18:10 echoes the sentiment of the well known medrash Rabbah 48:12 that the malachim visited on Pesach and were given K for P food and Sarah was in charge of making matzah, but this would not address the issue of seder.

Comment: Or remembering amalek?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot

Comment: @jake, is this not a duplicate thereof?

Comment: @msh210 seems to be to me. N. Price, if you still think this question has merit of it's own, please let me know. Welcome back, btw, we haven't seen you in a while! :D