# Can Jews eat hunted animals?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Are Jews allowed to eat hunted animals? That means the animals are dead before getting their necks cut.

I do not think that a large proportions of ancient Jews were hunters, but I would be surprised to find that there was not a single hunter in all of Jewish history.

Comment: Hunting for sport is strictly forbidden, and hunting for food will render the animal a *tereifah* if (as in the example you gave) you wound or kill the animal before slaughtering it. But that said, hunting is most certainly permissible. You could hunt for pelts, for example.

Comment: Interestingly, the hebrew (and biblical hebrew) word for hunting is Tzayad, which means trapping, not hunting. It seems to me that they would trap the wild animals and then slaughter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isaac was apparently not opposed to wild game. Was he not waiting for Esau to bring him some venison when Jacob came in and fooled him with mutton?

(I can't imagine how he was fooled since they taste so dissimilar)

Comment: That's true, but who's to say that he intended to shoot the deer? Maybe he wanted him to trap it, and slaughter it in a kosher manner.

Comment: Before Torah was given, not relevant!

Comment: @havarka That's a good point, but the Avos kept the Torah, even though they weren't commanded to.

Comment: @Shokhet Was Esav's Shechita even Kosher?

Comment: @DoubleAA Good point; I don't know. Would Yitzchak's shechita be kosher? Remember, he may not have been Jewish....

Comment: And Avos kept torah? How do they kept something they don't know? And if they know we're even in more problem? What does avos mean anyway? Forefathers?

Comment: @JimThio - Please see [this question and answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot/37805#37805). And yes, "avos" means "forefathers" or "fathers," and when we say "The Avos" we mean Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.

Answer (score 14):

No.

In theory (see *Yore Dea* chapters 3, 6, 7), it's possible to kill an animal with a really sharp arrow or thrown knife and render it kosher, but not practically.

Answer (score 3):

And, of course, to keep from dying (פיקוח נפש), though all non-animal food sources would have to prove or seem obviously insufficient, just as if all emergency rations were treif (which would be preferable, I believe, to killing an animal when there were something else you *could* eat that were permissible under the circumstances---please correct mke if I'm wrong).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  As written, this doesn't seem to answer the question.  If you're trying to say that hunting is ok for *pikuach nefesh* when no other food is available, could you [edit] to say that more directly?  Adding sources will strengthen your answer.  Without these changes this will probably be deleted; we reserve the answer space for answers, not discussion.  See [tour] for more about how the site works.  Thanks, and please do edit if you can make this fit better!

Comment: @MonicaCellio This answer may be better as a comment to the pre-existing answer....but this guy doesn't have the rep for that just yet. ....think it should be converted?

Answer (score -4):

The Torah specifically allows for hunting in Leviticus 17:13, provided that you pour out all the blood on the ground and cover it with earth. This is consistent with the Torah's instructions concerning the slaughter of animals in general, where you are required to pour out all the blood on the ground, but not required to cover it with earth. It is inconsistent with the ideas created in the Talmud, which seem to contradict the Torah on this point.

Comment: Im notsure what contradiction you see

Comment: You understand of hunting is an anachronism. The word can be about [trapping](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9918/jewish/Chapter-17.htm#showrashi=true&v=13) as well. And that is not an exclusively religious [claim](http://www.balashon.com/2007/01/tsade.html).

Comment: The animal had to be shechted after being trapped alive. However, there are those who say that this only occurred after the conquest of Eretz Yisrael. That is a different question and is not part of this question.