# Responsa on Hunting since the Noda B'Yehuda

Tags: halacha-theory, responsa

Many many years ago, the Noda B'Yehuda wrote his famous [responsa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43964/hunting-in-judaism) about hunting, noting that despite their not being a clear cut *issur*, it is not an activity that a Jew should engage in.

I have often marveled at the fact that it seems that no one ever challenged the Noda B'Yehuda's ruling. Nearly every area of Halacha has garnered contrarian and modern opinions on old questions, yet, as far as I know, nothing of the sort happened with hunting.

So, two questions. First, why might the Noda B'Yehuda's ruling have gone unchallenged? Why is it *so* compelling, that no one has argued on it since? Second, is that correct? Are there more modern responsa that offer a different ruling regarding hunting? I've never been able to locate one!

Comment: There are other rulings that concur or are more strict

Comment: https://music.amazon.com/es-ar/podcasts/8545a146-1b03-404f-9df2-d7f36e6e9e25/episodes/77ffd447-084b-4a4b-98dd-055bd1bb4a02/the-wild-huntsman-andrew-berns-hunting-scholarship-jewish-law-and-tradition

Comment: https://www.tabletmag.com/sections/community/articles/hunting-for-deer-and-meaning