# The status of Eliezer as a slave

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, conversion-to-judaism, slave-serve-eved-avadim, parashat-chaye-sara, eliezer

I am going to piece together a variety of bits of information, so please bear with me.

1. Eliezer was in charge of Avraham's house already before Avraham had his name changed (Bereishit 15:2)
2. Eliezer was an "eved" of Avraham (Bereishit 24 - there seems to be agreement that the eved not named refers to Eliezer).
3. Avraham circumcised all the males of his household, including non Jewish slaves (17:13, 23) which would include Eliezer.
4. A non-Jewish slave even not in Avraham's time is subject to some form of conversion during his servitude and must commit to the process within 12 months after being purchased or must be sold (from [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=pqqf-ccAAS8C&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=eved%20canaani%20conversion%20process&source=bl&ots=vbaiIqb7yx&sig=_6iKh6x8nNNU5Vu0H4vZiCYl1O8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vl1sUoqeOJPLkQf6xYHIAQ&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=eved%20canaani%20conversion%20process&f=false))
5. Eliezer's conversion was completed - he remained with Avraham for more than 12 months(Radak to 15:2 who states that Avraham actually gave the servant "Damesek" the new Ivri name of "Eliezer" which would point to a completed conversion, and would point to the idea that the avot [followed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4078/1362) the torah)

If these are the case, by the time Avraham sends Eliezer to find a wife for his son, he should not have resisted the possibility that Yitzchak could marry Eliezer's daughter. At that point, though Eliezer might once have been included in the curse on K'na'an (as discussed [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/parasha.aspx?id=125)), as a convert, Eliezer should have been viewed as a complete Jew and not called out in his status as convert (as discussed [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=AaMBNVzcY4gC&pg=PA277&lpg=PA277&dq=convert%20embarrass%20remind%20Jew&source=bl&ots=R9w8RGarwE&sig=iObnqw_Ng36i33BJbr3-nU9h5U0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=amBsUtKCK42qkQfYwYGYAQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=convert%20embarrass%20remind%20Jew&f=false)). So why does Avraham reject him and remind him of his ancestry as a K'na'ani?

Comment: I don't follow the last point. An Amoni who converts still can't marry a Jewess. Why do you think Eliezer's conversion would have allowed his daughter to marry Isaac?

Comment: What about the mother?  And if she converted, was it before the daughter was born?

Comment: I don't understand the question, an Eved Knani could only marry a Shifcha and any children from that marriage are Avodim Kenanim whom a Jew can't marry unless they are sent free - so why does Avraham Avini have to entertain the thought of ever freeing Eliezer's daughter? Secondly, exactly because Eliezer is still an Eved that means that the curse to Kenan that his children would be Avodim is being fulfilled!

Comment: @MonicaCellio I can't find any info about Eliezer's wife and daughter so I can't pinpoint the timing but I would think that since the child of an eved k'na'ani is still an eved, she too would have gone through the conversion process and double AA this would make her marriagable as she would no longer be from bnot hak'na'ani either because her father is no longer a k'na'ani or she is no longer one. In fact, one could say that her mother's status is immaterial because she falls under "bnot ha'k'na'ani" and not "bnot hak'na'aniah" (as in moavi vlo moavia)

Comment: @MeirZirkind if there was no hope because of the eved status then avraham would not need to justify his decision via the k'na'an curse. If the k'na'an curse was the primary problem then the conversion should have obviated that (and even if it hadn't eliminated it, the conversion status should not have been brought up).

Comment: It was Eliezer's hope and Avraham was telling him that ha had no intention of removing Noach's curse even an iota. The conversion does not take away the Eved status and Avraham did not bring it up - you did!

Comment: @MeirZirkind  Bereishit 24:3. Avraham brings it up to Eliezer's face when he reminds Eliezer not to hope that Yitzchak could marry Eliezer's daughter because he won't allow Yitzchak to marry a K'na'ani (rashi to 24:39). Avraham is saying that despite the conversion, Eliezer is still a K'na'ani. If he was truly of the household (as a sincere convert would be) telling him of his roots, let alone limiting him because of them, would be wrong.

Comment: @Danno I'm still not sure I follow. The child of a Mitzri convert who marries a Mitzrit convert is still Asur. The child of an Amoni convert who marries a Jewess (b'isur) is still Asur. Why do you think his daughter would be muttar?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure that the child would be muttar -- I am trying to understand on which basis the child is assur. If it is because Eliezer is a k'na'ani then calling him the head of the household and saying he had an Ivri name is empty. His conversion has no lasting value. If it did, then reminding him of the earlier status would be wrong.

Comment: @Danno Why does the Amoni-who-can't-marry-a-Jew's conversion have no lasting value??? He's Jewish!!

Comment: @DoubleAA - good question but not precisely on point: Eliezer's daughter would be considered a k'na'aniah -- her father's history wouldn't invalidate her (if you equate it to amoni, we know that the law for amoniah is to allow marriage). And, in the mishne torah, the Rambam says that children of the 7 nations' converts CAN marry in (unless I am misreading Issurei Biah 12:22) - the ones who can't are listed as amon, moav, edom and mitzrayim, not K'na'an.

Comment: @Danno I'm not making a technical equation for all the details, only showing you that you haven't shown why conversion should save him or his daughter from being considered forbidden. And don't bring proof from later halacha; as you see it is clear that they aren't referring to that.

Comment: @DoubleAA so are you saying that this statement should be taken in an halachik vacuum, ignoring any laws regarding conversion, the nations, or anything else as they are all later halacha? If so, then the entire question is moot, indeed, because it is predicated on laws of geirut which are later. I am simply trying to apply the corpus of law evenly backwards so that if it is invoked in one aspect, it is invoked in all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing 2 types of conversions for slaves.

See the Rambam in [הלכות איסורי ביאה פרק יג](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5113.htm)

> ז:  כשם שמולין ומטבילין את הגרים, כך מולין ומטבילין את העבדים הנלקחים מן הגויים לשם עבדות.  הלוקח עבד מן הגוי, וקדם העבד וטבל לשם בן חורין--קנה עצמו:  והוא שיאמר בעת טבילה, הריני טובל בפניכם לשם גירות; ואם טבל בפני רבו, אינו צריך לפרש, אלא כיון שטבל, נשתחרר
>
> ח:  לפיכך צריך רבו לתוקפו במים, עד שיעלה והוא תחת שיעבודו, ומודיעו בפני הדיינין, שלשם עבדות מטבילו; ואין העבד טובל אלא בפני שלושה וביום כגר, שמקצת גירות היא
>
> ט:  כשישתחרר העבד, צריך טבילה אחרת בפני שלושה ביום, שבה תיגמר גירותו, ויהיה כישראל; ואין צריך לקבל עליו מצוות, ולהודיעו עיקרי הדת, שכבר הודיעוהו, כשטבל לשם עבדות.   ובמקוה הכשר לטבילת נידה, שם מטבילין את הגרים ואת העבדים ואת המשוחררים; וכל דבר שחוצץ בנידה, חוצץ בגרים ובעבדים ובמשוחררים

A slave is *converted* - with Mila and Tevila - after being bought. He then has the status of an Even Kna'ani.

If and when he is freed, he again needs to dip in the Mikveh - in front of 3 kosher witnesses - in order to gain the status of Jew.

Thus, **Eliezer Eved Avraham - even after his conversion - was an Eved Kna'ani**. Note the stress on Kna'ani, even though slaves could be from any nation. It's as if Chazal want to pre-empt your question by referring  to all post-conversion-slaves as Eved Kna'ani.