# Pregnant animals and kashrut

Tags: kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht

If an animal is pregnant and you slaughter it, what is the status of the fetus? Does the stage of development matter like in regards to eggs?

Comment: http://5tjt.com/the-new-ben-pekuah-meat/

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48408/how-could-avraham-feed-his-guests-milk/48409#48409

Answer (score 1):

The mishna in the [fourth chapter](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Chullin.4.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) of Chullin covers this topic and the gemara ([Chullin 68a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.68a.1-17?lang=bi) and ff) develops it. As a summary, R Steinsaltz [writes](https://www.ou.org/life/torah/masechet_hullin_68a74b/) that when a pregnant animal is slaughtered its fetus becomes permitted together with all of the rest of the animal’s internal organs.

> In any case, it is clear from the Mishnah that in such a case the
>   fetus becomes permitted as a result of its mother’s slaughter; in the
>   event that the fetus’ head came out it is considered to have been
>   born, and as an independent entity would not become permitted by means
>   of its mother’s slaughter. [...]
>
> Rabbi Yochanan teaches that if the slaughtered animal was opened and
>   that the fetus had not developed into an animal, rather it has the
>   appearance of a dove, it is forbidden. The Gemara explains that this
>   law is based on the fact that the Torah requires that an animal have
>   split hooves if it is to be eaten (see Devarim 14:6). At the same
>   time, if the fetus has the form of an animal – even without split
>   hooves – Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai teaches that it is deemed kosher
>   based on the fact that the same passage talks about a single hoof.

See also [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/gemara/qa-daf-yomi-review/through-what-mechanism-does-an-animal-fetus-become-permitted-via-the-mother-animals-shechita/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the animal is considered slaughtered (Ben pakuah). 
In fact, if two of these animals give birth to a baby, the baby is also considered slaughtered. (Shulchan Aruch)

Comment: The question was in relation to the fetus. Also when referencing the SA, it would be helpful to give the exact reference.