# Is there a detailed explanation for Bereishis 18:8?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, rashi, meat-and-milk, vayera, abraham

וַיִּקַּח חֶמְאָה וְחָלָב וּבֶן־הַבָּקָר אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה וַיִּתֵּן לִפְנֵיהֶם וְהֽוּא־עֹמֵד עֲלֵיהֶם תַּחַת הָעֵץ וַיֹּאכֵֽלוּ׃ 
I know the Torah was not given at this time, nor had the Sages explained the separation of meat and dairy, but is there a detailed explanation for food served here?  I know Rashi explains that Avraham served the dairy before the meat, which does make sense.  I'm wondering if anyone has any other answers or knows of any sources that explain this further.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34288/if-jews-dont-eat-cheeseburgers-why-did-abraham-serve-a-calf-with-milk/34290#34290

Comment: Thanks, I looked briefly but didn't find anything.

Comment: The Malbim explains that he created a calf using Sefer Yetzirah(manipulating nature using the aleph beis) which can be eaten with milk.

Comment: (WARNING: My own speculation, not a rabbi's) Perhaps Avraham served one malach meat, the other bread, and the last one dairy?

Comment: Allen welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your first two questions! I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!