# PTIJ: Mouthful of Mitzvos

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Torah gives us (*B'midbar* 15:39) the cause and effect that are supposed to occur when we are in the proximity of a *tzitzis*:

> 'וְהָיָה לָכֶם לְצִיצִת וּרְאִיתֶם אֹתוֹ וּזְכַרְתֶּם אֶת **כָּל מִצְו‍ֹת ה**
>
> It should be *tzitzis* for you, and you should **look at** it and **remember** all of God's commandments.

We know that when [the Torah says](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68958/3) "remember" in a context like this it means "recite verbally", just like the commandment for *kidush* on *shabas*, which Chazal understood, and Rambam (29:1) said explicitly, must be accomplished through speaking:

> מצות עשה מן התורה לקדש את יום השבת **בדברים**, שנאמר "**זכור** את יום השבת לקדשו"
>
> [It is] a positive commandment from the Torah to sanctify the day of *shabas* **with words**, as it is said, "**remember** the day of *shabas* to sanctify it"

So when one **sees** a *tzitzis* one is obligated to **recite** all of the *mitzvos*. This would apply equally well to clothing worn by others as by oneself, since sometimes other people are even more aware of what you are wearing than you are, such as when you are wearing *kil'ayim* (10:29) and don't know it until it is spotted and ripped off of you in the street - "הרואה כלאים של תורה על חבירו אפילו היה מהלך בשוק קופץ לו וקורעו עליו מיד".

Now, that is a lot of *mitzvos* to recite - 613 by most counts although [YמMV](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.24a.25?lang=bi) - each time a person sees a *tzitzis*, especially in areas [where it is common](https://www.flickr.com/photos/iocmedia/4906399647/in/photostream/) to keep them visibly hanging out. And it becomes even more difficult to say them all when one wants *l'kayem* the added level of "אחרי מצותיך תרדוף **נפשי**", necessarily leaving the person out of breath by the time they even start.

- How can one fit in all that reciting of *mitzvos* and still have time left in the day?
- Does the list have to be the [סמ"ג](https://books.google.at/books?id=O6thAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) or would it be enough to say just the [סמ"ק](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLIS/he/ManuScript/Pages/Item.aspx?ItemID=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS000171934) or even the [סמ"ק](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=523)?
- Is there a *havinenu* one can say instead?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

Very easy solution. It's already done each morning...

All one needs to do is recite the words תלמוד תורה because תלמוד תורה כנגד כולם. Talmud Torah is equivalent to doing all the mitzvoth. Saying the words is equivalent to saying all the mitzvoth.

Answer (score 2):

As you cite in the OP, Chavakuk boiled all the Mitzvos down to one:

> וצדיק באמונתו יחיה
>
> A Tzaddik - in his faith will he live

You just need to say this three-word phrase and you’ll be good.