# Avraham Kosher for Pesach Mustard

Tags: passover, vayera, abraham, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Seeing that Avraham served the angels mustard on Pesach ([Bava Metzia 86b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.86b?lang=bi)),

> ולמה לי תלתא תסגי בחד אמר רב חנן בר רבא כדי להאכילן שלש לשונות **בחרדל**
>   אמר רבי תנחום בר חנילאי לעולם אל ישנה אדם מן המנהג שהרי משה עלה למרום
>   ולא אכל לחם מלאכי השרת ירדו למטה ואכלו לחם ואכלו סלקא דעתך אלא אימא
>   נראו כמי שאכלו ושתו
>
> The Gemara asks: And why do I need three calves? One calf should be
>   sufficient for three guests. Rav Ḥanan bar Rava said: Abraham prepared
>   three calves in order to feed the guests three tongues with **mustard**
>   particular delicacy.

and the Rema says not to have mustard on Pesach (O.C. [464:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.464.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> **הגה** והמנהג שלא לאכול חרדל כלל בפסח אפי' נתערב קודם פסח
>   דהוי כמיני קטניות שנוהגין בו איסור:‏

Why would Avraham have served mustard if he [kept](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.26.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.26.5.2&lang2=bi) any precautionary measure to avoid transgression:

> וישמר משמרתי. גזרות להרחקה על האזהרות שבתורה, כגון שניות לעריות ושבות
>   לשבת (יבמות כ"א):‏
>
> וישמר משמרתי AND KEPT MY CHARGE — This refers to precautionary
>   measures which are intended to make us avoid the infringement of
>   Biblical prohibitions: such are the Rabbinical inhibition of marriage
>   between relatives in the second degree and the Rabbinical regulations
>   regarding not doing certain acts on the Sabbath.

Comment: *Kitniyos* is only a *minhag*...

Comment: It means Avraham was a Sefardi.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot

Comment: If you are asking if he didn't practice the custom the Rama mentions, then obviously he didn't as seen in your source and i don't know what else you are seeking from us. If you want to ask something based on a Gemara in Yoma, then do so.

Comment: @DavidKenner Clearly. Sounds like the start to a good Purim Torah...

Comment: Your source only says he kept *gezeiros derabbanan*, not *minhagim*.

Comment: And how did Yaakov Aveinu marry two sisters while both were alive? It's almost as if they'd never read the Torah in the form we know it, let alone the Oral Law ....;

Comment: @DoubleAA Can we get this closed as a dupe of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4078/9682?