# How did Noach know which animals were kosher prior to matan torah?

Tags: torah-study, noach-noah-the-man

How did Noach know which animals were tahor?

The Rabbi Chaim of Volozhin comments about this in his work, ["Nefesh HaChaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Nefesh_HaChayim%2C_Gate_I.21.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and says that the mefarshim say that Noach learned torah.

Which Mefarshim is he talking about?

[This link mentions that it is discussed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot#:%7E:text=As%20a%20proof%20that%20Torah%20was%20learned%20before%20it%20was%20given%2C%20our%20sages%20point%20out%20that%20if%20Noach%20didn%27t%20have%20Torah%2C%20how%20would%20he%20know%20which%20animals%20were%20pure%2C%20and%20which%20ones%20were%20impure.%20(many%20other%20similar%20proofs%20are%20brought%20as%20well))  but does not specify where.

Comment: They came by themselves. Seven of each kosher and two of non kosher. He didn’t have to know beforehand

Comment: howdy @Chatzkel . i updated my question.

Comment: You also assume Tahor means kosher

Comment: "Which Mefarshim is he talking about?" - The Nefesh HaChayim actually says that the Gemara in Yoma 28b and different Midrashim talk about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rashi on the passuk [7:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.7.2.1?lang=he)

> הטהורה. הָעֲתִידָה לִהְיוֹת טְהוֹרָה לְיִשְׂרָאֵל; לָמַדְנוּ שֶׁלָּמַד נֹחַ תּוֹרָה (שם פ' כ"ו):
> הטהורה

> CLEAN—It means those cattle which will in future be permitted to Israel as clean; we thus learn that Noah studied the Torah

Comment: Thank you, your swift wisdom is truly wonderful.

Comment: See the [Hizquni](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Genesis.7.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) there.