# What laws prior to Torah taught Noach (in Bereshit 8:20) that birds [Zevachim 116a:2] or bulls [Avot D'Rabbi Natan 1:8] or sheep were kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, noachide-laws, noach-noah-the-man, tradition

Although Shmuel b. Nachmani [Sanhedrin 108b:6] claimed Noach distinguished טְּהוֹרָה ‘clean’ animals (referenced in Bereshit 7:2) based only on their status as אִישׁ וְאִשְׁתּוֹ ‘husband & wife’, **what laws prior to Torah taught Noach (in Bereshit 8:20) that birds [Zevachim 116a:2] or bulls [Avot D'Rabbi Natan 1:8] or sheep [Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 23:13] were kosher?**

https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.8.20?lang=bi&with=Talmud

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135198/how-did-noach-know-which-animals-were-kosher-prior-to-matan-torah/135200#135200

Comment: @Chatzkel - Thank you for your link about Rashi’s definition of ‘Tehorah’, but it does not answer which oral/written torah was studied by Noach. * Did Methushelach have oral Torah for Noach to understand birds, bulls, sheep were kosher?