# Chasam Sofer and Pardes Yosef

Tags: torah-study

Culled from a lengthy answere [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot#:%7E:text=Thus%20far%2C%20all,this%20idea%20literally.).

Can anyone help pinpoint some topics covered by the Chasam Sofer or others about the SPECIFIC mitzvos the avos did.

Please cite any sources given, links are preferred.

Comment: Yitzchak established the Mitzvah of Ma’aser (Rambam Hilchos Melacim 9:1)

Comment: Esav invented the mitzvah of tithing salt

Comment: See Parshas Derachim