How could the patriarchs have observed the ritual commandments?
The Sources says that the patriarchs and those they taught followed halacha.¹
There are two types of commandments: Ethical and ritual.  I understand that the ethical  commandments could have been derived by logical thinking, and also from the Noahide laws that had already been given before the patriarchs.  But how could the patriarchs possibly have derived the ritual commandments?  The Midrash says that Lot even observed Pessah, long before the Exodus [Genesis Rabbah 48:12]!  How could they be prescient of Purim, Hanukkah, Pessah, etc., and in particular their specific dates?  Or shaatnez, Shema, tzitzit, tefillin, taharat hamishpacha, etc.?  Any commentaries on this question?
Some say that the ritual commandments were revealed to Abraham supernaturally. Let me add then: What is the benefit in him observing them, thereby revealing to all those around him (through the holidays) what the future will be?

¹Sources:

עֵ֕קֶב אֲשֶׁר־שָׁמַ֥ע אַבְרָהָ֖ם בְּקֹלִ֑י וַיִּשְׁמֹר֙ מִשְׁמַרְתִּ֔י מִצְוֺתַ֖י חֻקּוֹתַ֥י וְתוֹרֹתָֽי׃
Because Abraham obeyed my voice, and kept my charge, my commandments, my statutes, and my laws. [Genesis 26:5]


Abraham our Patriarch fulfilled the entire Torah, even the mitzvah of the joining of cooked foods, as it is stated: "Torotai My Torahs". [Since the term is in the plural, it indicates that Abraham kept two Torahs:] one, the Written Torah, and one, the Oral Torah. [Yoma 28b]


Jacob observed Shabbat before it was given. [Bereshit Rabbah 79:7]


Based on their intuitions, the Patriarchs kept mitzvot and observed Shabbat [Peninei Halakhah, Shabbat 1:3:2]


...opinions offered by the Talmud and subsequent scholars that the patriarchs observed even minutiae of later rabbinical ordinances. [Rabbeinu Bahya, Bereshit 26:5:4]


Are you asking how they could have existed or how the avos knew about them

The Gemoro in Yoma there says he even kept eruvei tavshillin. And notes Bereishis Rabbah 64:4 whcih said he also knew the halachos of eruvei chatzeiros!

@Dov A more reasonable version of Yoma has eruv techumin not tavshilin

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/avot-keeping-mitzvot

Many Rabbonim discuss this question. The common answer is that Avraham could sense the mitzvot from the very sensitivity his great and lofty soul had towards spirituality. His "kidneys" counselled him to order to figure out all of the mitzvot. There is that famous Rashi about how Avraham kept Pesach etc.
This is explained in the Zohar to mean that the Jewish soul has 613 "limbs", each corresponding to a Mitzva. Avraham could sense this through his sensitivity and emunah. This even applied to "chukim" and ritualistic commandments, even edut; mitzvot that pertain to an event that hadn't even happened yet, like Pesach.
Sources so far: Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer 26 with Radal (who also brings Nedarim 32a), cf. Sefer HaYashar 24. Also, Ben Ish Chai Rav Pealim 4, Malbim on Bereshit 22:4.
He also learned in the home of Noach and the Yeshiva of Shem (see Y JD's answer, both of whom were very holy tzaddikim, who had extensive knowledge from angels, nevua and sefarim passed down from previous generations, even going back to Adam. Finally, he also learned with Gavriel the angel.
Sources: Sefer HaYashar pp. 24-25, Yalkut Meam Loez, Maaseh Avraham (from Otzar Midrashim 1, pp.3-4, 6). Please see Dov's answer for more sources for my points, as well as another, important way that Avraham learned about the mitzvot
As for what is the benefit, I am not sure the question is particularly compelling because it has an obvious answer: for the reward. Otherwise, for more nuance, one could look into the status of Avraham as a Jew - many hold, such as Parashat Derachim, that he became a fully fledged Jew the moment he dedicated himself to serving Hashem at which point he became obligated in the mitzvot.
See this Rosh David (by the Chida), which brings lots of opinions, in his discussion on why Avraham waited until age 99 to perform the Brit Milah. It even brings an opinion that he was a "partially obligated Jew", and therefore had to avoid the aveirot, but wasn't obligated in the positive mitzvot, which he either did voluntarily (for the reward, the tikkun, etc), or waited until he was commanded (such as the Brit Milah).
As for "revealing the future", that would make it's own (great imo) question.

I recommend trying to get hold of the work "Avraham Avinu", the Elzas Edition by R Chaim Zvi Noyek, which like the "Let my nation" series, works through all the midrashim and tells the story of Avraham, and it contains extensive footnotes and appendices.

Even if the ritual commandments were revealed to Abraham supernaturally in the manner you describe, what is the benefit in him observing them, thereby revealing to all those around him (through the holidays) what the future will be?

@MauriceMizrahi see edit

There are several sources about this.
Like @Rabbi_Kaii mentioned about the kidneys, note the Avos DeRabbi Nosson 33:1:

ולא היה אחד מהם שיהלך בדרכי הקב״ה עד שבא אברהם אבינו והלך בדרכי הקב״ה שנא׳ (בראשית כ״ו:ה׳) עקב אשר שמע אברהם בקולי וגו' (וכי תורה אחת שמר והלא תורות הרבה שמר) אלא מלמד שזימן הקב״ה לאברהם אבינו ב׳ כליותיו כשני חכמים והיו מבינות אותו ויועצות אותו ומלמדות אותו חכמה כל הלילה שנא׳ (תהילים ט״ז:ז׳) אברך את ה׳ אשר יעצני אף לילות יסרוני כליותי
and there was not one among them who walked in the ways of the Holy Blessed One until Abraham our forefather came along, and he walked in the ways of the Holy Blessed One, as it says (Genesis 26:5), “Because Abraham heeded My call [and kept My charge, My commandments, My rules, and My Torahs.]” (But there is only one Torah! How could he have kept Torahs, plural?) This teaches that the Holy Blessed One planted two inner voices (lit. kidneys) in Abraham, like two wise men, who helped him understand, advised him, and taught him wisdom all night long, as it says (Psalms 16:7), “I will bless the Eternal who has advised me. Even at night, the voices inside of me [lit., my kidneys] have admonished me.”

As also has been mentioned, Avraham maintained a relationship with Malkitzedek/Shem where he learnt Torah. Refer to the posuk in Bereishis 14:18 where one view in Bereishis Rabbah 43:6 writes:

וְרַבָּנָן אָמְרֵי תּוֹרָה גִּלָּה לוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (משלי ט, ה): לְכוּ לַחֲמוּ בְלַחְמִי וּשְׁתוּ בְּיַיִן מָסָכְתִּי
The Rabbis say: He revealed Torah [precepts] to him, as it is stated: “Come, partake of my bread, and drink of the wine that I have mixed” (Proverbs 9:5).

At the heart of it was his relationship with Hashem. All the avos spoke exclusively with Hashem (refer to Midrash HaGadol 17:22 which notes that when G-d spoke to them he did so exclusively without the Chayos or Merkavah etc.). Indeed note the Pesikta DeRav Kahana 5 which writes that Hashem showed Avraham four things - one of which was Torah (the other three being Korbanos, Gehennom and the Four Kingdoms - Bavel, Paras, Yavan and Edom).

I know this, and listed many sources in my question.

No you listed many sources saying that the avos performed the mitzvos. I have listed three reasons as per your question as to how they came to know them...

Maybe it was the meditative practices he did as a child which led him to the conclusion that HaShem is the creator and king of the Universe in the first place(I presume he continued) ... this isn't an alternative proposition, maybe those exercises sensitize the body to readily sense the D!vine.

A Mechanism(s) is(are) plausibly described in Patach Eliyahu: https://www.sefaria.org/Tikkunei_Zohar.17a.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patach_Eliyahu

Very good on the point about Hashem revealing to him the mitzvot. That's actually the best answer on this page imo!

@הראל the midrashim and kabbalah describe Avraham's soul as being particularly lofty, and it was due to that that he could sense the mitzvot

So not a product of deeds or effort at @RabbiKaii? Or were the deeds just a sequential consequence of the lofty soul? Leading to the rest ...

Extending the answer of Rabbi Kaii, we know that Shem was Melchizedek of Salem the priest of G-d most high (Bereshis 14:18). We also have Bereshis Rabba 46:5,

Rabbi Yishmael says: Abraham was a High Priest, as it is stated: “The Lord has taken an oath and will not renounce it: You are a priest forever…” (Psalms 110:4), and it is stated elsewhere: “You shall circumcise the flesh of your orla” (Genesis 17:11). [Abraham wondered,] from where should he become circumcised? If he would become circumcised from the ear, he would be unfit to perform sacrifices; if from the mouth, he would be unfit to perform sacrifices; if from the heart, he would be unfit to perform sacrifices. From where could he become circumcised and still be fit to sacrifice? You must say, it is the orla of the body.

Therefore, one has to conclude that Avraham either learned the ritual law from Noach, Shem, and Ever or / and it was revealed to him as a covenant of Bris Millah.
There is a dual purpose of the ritual law. It was a vehicle to "get closer" to Hashem, i.e. to develop attachment, deveikus. At the time of Abraham all religions were based on active practice of ritual laws, which had strong symbolism and certainly Judaism also had to have such a vehicle to attract a following in opposition to Egypt, Bavel, K'naan, which all had developed religions with epic texts detailing rituals. Additionally, the ritual law can be used as means of kapparah to erase the aftereffect of sins that one could have done.

I agree about the importance of rituals.  The ritual commandments preserve Judaism.  The ethical commandments make Judaism worthy of being preserved.  But my issue here is with revealing history by celebrating Purim, Hanukkah, Pessah, etc., long before the commemorated events occur.  Something's not right.  At any rate, there are no halachic issues here.

@MauriceMizrahi I have some ideas. But need to think how to formulate them. It is related to the argument between Ramban and Rashi whether Torah is written sequentially or out of order. Ramban also believed that since Hashem looked in the Torah and created the world, this means that He had an idea of what the mitzvos should be (and directed history accordingly). It seems the question that you are asking goes to that school of thinking, even if it looks counterintuitive to historical development.
